# mouse:wheel event for canvas is not working in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am working with fabricjs to build a tool where I can add text and shapes on the image. I am also adding zoom and panning controls. I have pasted code below for zooming on mouse:wheel event but for some reason the event is not being detected, and not working. I have tried setting selection attribute of canvas to true as well but that does not work either. Any help related to what I am doing wrong here is appreciated. Thanks.

```
class FabricEditor {

    constructor(image_name, image_url, id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.image_url = image_url;
        this.image_name = image_name;
        this.canvas = new window.fabric.Canvas('fabric-editor', { isDrawingMode: false });
        
        // Enable panning
        this.canvas.allowTouchScrolling = true;
        this.canvas.selection = false;


        let parent = this;
        // Enable zooming
        this.canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function (opt) {
            console.log('Detecting mouse wheel', opt);
            var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
            var zoom = parent.canvas.getZoom();
            zoom *= 0.999 ** delta;

            // Set limits on zooming
            if (zoom > 5) zoom = 5;
            if (zoom < 1) zoom = 1;

            parent.canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY }, zoom);
            opt.e.preventDefault();
            opt.e.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: did you found any solution to this issue

Comment: I tested the code and it's working for me.